# IntelliTest Won't Create Test Project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, intellitest

I have created a new project, which I would like to test with IntelliTest.
I click inside a class/method and select **Create IntelliTest**.
When I click okay in the dialog box, IntelliTest acts as if a project is created, but nothing shows up.
There is no new project in the Solution Explorer, no new files created when looking in File Explorer, no error messages and no compile errors.

The output from IntelliTest shows no errors:

```
loading settings from TestGeneration.Extensions.IntelliTest.NUnit
Creating Project MyProject.Tests
finished
```

If I run IntelliTest and try to save it, I get an error:
[image: IntelliTest error]

It seems to make no difference when I change the settings or test framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Restoring the default templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms247116.aspx) seem to solve the problem.

Comment: That error dialog above - that should not be coming. If it does, then it indicates a bug. The next time you see it, can you please report this using the Send a Smile feature in the VS IDE, please.