# IntelliTest don't Create Test Project

Tags: unit-testing, uwp, xamarin.forms, intellitest

i have Xamarin.Forms PLC and UWP project in a solution and when i tried to create a unit test using IntelliTest it just says finish and nothing show up or created i tried so many times but nothing happened, i tried with every framework  but nothing.
[image]

i'm trying to create tests for the PCL not the UWP.

the same problem is in this question but it's solution didn't work with me [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36435197/intellitest-wont-create-test-project)

Environment :
Win10 Ent. with latest update  build 15063.138

VS2015.3

Xamarin.Forms latest version.

Comment: Is there anything in the output window?

Comment: @KenTucker just one word "finished"

Comment: If you look in the project folder is there a test project added but not added to solution?

Comment: No there is not

Comment: Are you trying to create an xUnit test, an NUnit test, or an MSTest test?

Comment: Yes I tried and nothing.